# Using an mxf file but transparency won't appear

Tags: transparency

I am fairly new to blender. I have an mxf file that I exported out of davinci resolve with the alpha data enabled. When bringing the mxf file back into resolve. The Transparency works but in blender the black will not go away. I am in cycles and I will attach a screenshot any info on this would help immensely.

Thanks[image]

Comment: I cannot tell what I am looking at. Also, what do you mean, “when bringing the Mxf file back into resolve [period]”? That is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Davinci Resolve (video editing program) is where I exported the Video file from as an mxf file with Alpha Channel data. I want the black to be transparent on this video file. It does contain the alpha data. However, the black is still there when it should be transparent. The sentence regarding resolve I am referring to Davinci Resolve. When I bring the MXF file back into that program the alpha channel works and it is transparent but does not work in Blender. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it does. I do not know what’s going on here, but I suspect since MXF is kind of a rare format that blender may be reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually just exported the file as a TIFF or PNG image sequence and then imported it into resolve stitching it together as sequence and that corrected the issue! I kind of just stumbled on it.

Answer (score 0):

This situation seems easy enough for me to resolve, just set the film transparency in the rendering, under the *Rendering* tab, *Film > Transparency*.

[image: where to set transparency]

Comment: Also ! thanks you allowed me to know if it possible to read mxf on blender

Comment: If you have a different question please use the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top right. You are unlikely to get an answer here